# jquery only returns the value of the first row

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to get the value from each price row when i focused on the quantity input , the first row worked fine but the other rows keep alerting me the exact same value from the first row

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
include ("dblink.php");

?>

<form method="POST">
Customer Name: <input type="text" name="customer"><br />
Order Date : <input type="date" name="date"><br />
<br />

<table border='1' style='width:50%'>
    <tr>
        <th> Item Name </th>
        <th> Price </th>
        <th> Quantity </th>
        <th> Total </th>
    </tr>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if(!$result){
        die ("SQL Error : " . mysqli_error($link));
    }
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='name'>" . $row->name . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='itemprice' value='" . $row->price . "'>" . $row->price . "</td>";
?>
    <td><input type="number" class="quantity"></td>
    <td><div class="total"></div></td>
<?php
    }
    echo "</tr>";
?>  
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.quantity').focus(function() {
            var text = $('.itemprice').attr('value');
            alert(text);
        })
    });
</script>
```

i am still learning about jquery and ajax , please help

Comment: You probably have to iterate using `$.each()` and compile all the rows values into one alert.

Answer (score 1):

First `<tr>` is in while loop and `</tr>` is out while loop. So `</tr>` must be move in while loop.

Second if you use class selector of jquery, jquery return first value. So `$('.itemprice').attr('value')` return value attribute from first of all `.itemprice`. You can select siblings of `.quantity` to get value of `.itemprice` that be near of this `.quantity`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
    include ("dblink.php");
    ?>

    <form method="POST">
        Customer Name: <input type="text" name="customer"><br />
        Order Date : <input type="date" name="date"><br />
        <br />

        <table border='1' style='width:50%'>
            <tr>
                <th> Item Name </th>
                <th> Price </th>
                <th> Quantity </th>
                <th> Total </th>
            </tr>
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

            if(!$result){
            die ("SQL Error : " . mysqli_error($link));
        }
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class='name'>" . $row->name . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='itemprice' value='" . $row->price . "'>" . $row->price . "</td>";
        ?>
        <td><input type="number" class="quantity"></td>
        <td><div class="total"></div></td>
        echo "</tr>";
        <?php
    }
    ?>  
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.quantity').focus(function() {
            var text = $(this).siblings('.itemprice').attr('value');
            alert(text);
        })
    });
</script>
```